# Pre-allocation of multiple struct's - same struct

Tags: c, pointers, memory, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have the following:

```
typedef struct _wrapper {
    int num;
    foo *bar;
    pthread_mutext_t lock;
    struct _wrapper *prev;
    struct _wrapper *next;
} wrapper;
```

You can probably already tell where I'm going with this: I want to load, in advance, multiple wrappers at run time to save having to use malloc calls every time I need a wrapper. I'm going to use try_lock to cycle through to find an available wrapper, and after cycling through all and not finding any available, allocate an additional few with malloc() again and add them to the linked list of wrappers.

I can build it properly with a for loop executing individual malloc() calls and building the linked list like that and simply modify *next and *prev for each cycle in the loop. What I'm trying to find out is if there's a way to essentially create them all within a single malloc() statement (i.e. (wrapper *)malloc(sizeof(wrapper)*50); . My problem there is - how do I go about building all of these wrappers and putting them at the correct locations in memory to ensure I don't stomp on top of the other(s) ? A shove in a good direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I love how someone down voted this... Whoever did that must not have gotten very much love as a child.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can allocate an array of 50 wrappers with `malloc(50*sizeof wrapper)`
2. They will be accessible as `p[0]`, ... `p[49]` if you store the result of malloc into a wrapper* p, you can also use `p`, ... `p+49` when you need pointers (such as when handling your linked list)
3. That may complicate additional allocation and deallocation if you can't do it for the whole set at once, but such kind of memory pool is a common way to speed up allocation.
4. Don't forget that you have to initialize the mutex, allocating it won't be enough.

Comment: Much appreciated... I just realised a scary thing, though. The intention was to use try mutex to loop through the wrapper list until one that's available is found, and allocate more as needed in pools of 20ish, then free them as the load reduced... However, what I'm now realising is that if I do that with the mutex, I'm going to have an issue with free'ing the mutex afterwards. One thread does the job creation to send to the scheduler, and submits it. A worker thread will be the one to grab the wrapper, use it, and then try to free it. Can a thread free a mutex it didn't create?

Comment: Do you mean destroy or unlock? A thread unlocking a mutex that it hasn't locked if UB IIRC. Destroying should not be an issue, but I'd be pay attention of not destroying a mutex which has threads locked on it.

Comment: Got ya... On that note, seems like I'm going to have to allocate some worker threads to handle rummaging through the wrappers and then signal them from the other thread using them in order to have the originating thread that locked the mutex unlock it... Thank you for the input, very much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you make a single malloc for 50 wrappers, what you will be creating is an array of wrappers, allocated in dynamic memory.

To get the address of the i'th wrapper, you have to add `(i * sizeof(wrapper))` to the pointer returned by malloc. Using this address, you can fill the pointers *prev and *next for each of the 50 wrappers.

However, while possible, I would not suggest it for the following reasons.

1. It does not generate clean code.
2. Adding further elements has to be handled separately
3. Free will be simple if the list does not have to grow, but will have different cases if the list grows past 50.

Comment: So that being said, is it better to just individually malloc() for each wrapper and assign next and prev then and there during each iteration, and just free each one as need be? And, what's the overhead (not that it's as important in a case like this, I suppose) when malloc'ing 50 wrappers individually versus in one big hit? And how does that affect whether or not the memory will be contiguous ?

Comment: It is better to individually malloc, as mentioned above. The overhead should not be too much to do so, but that depends on your system. The memory will not be contiguous. It is not required to be so, as you have pointers to the next and previous location available.

Comment: I agree that the requirement isn't there - but wouldn't the performance be degraded a bit by the memory not being contiguous? Or is the degradation really not enough to be concerned over? 

The more I think about it, also, it's better to perform the individual malloc()'s in the fact that the space is growable, with the intent to free them back down to 50 if the demand for them reduces. If I were to end up freeing the first one, I get the feeling that would result in a free of all 50 from the original malloc... 

I appreciate the input, guys. I'll stick with individual malloc()'s for each.